# How to make a groupbox transparent in VB

Tags: vb.net

The question pretty much says it all, I've tried setting the backcolour to transparent in the properties section, but it didnt seem to work. I have a picture behind the groupbox that I need to show through it. Is there a specific way of doing this?

Thanks

Comment: I think its winforms. im using VS 05 if that helps..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The transparent property doesn't work for overlapping controls. I guess that you have your picture in a PictureBox?

You can fix this in at least two ways:

1) perhaps the easiest is to place both your picture AND GroupBox *within* a Panel (you set the Panel's BackgroundImage property). That will work. Then the GroupBox and Panel aren't technically overlapping, but the GruopBox is a child to the Panel. That requires no code and you see exactly what you get directly in the Forms Designer.

2) Paint the picure directly onto the form yourself in in one of the form's OnPaint or OnPaintBackground methods.

Comment: Thanks for the help! My form looks much better now =D

Comment: I had a similar problem in C#, and after reading this answer helped me to find the real solution.  Instead of creating a picture box that covers the whole form, I changed it to put the image in the property 'BackgroundImage' of the form.  Then setting the 'Backcolor' of the group box to 'Transparent' clearly show the background image.

Answer (score 1):

the Topic is too old, but I will just place my answer for sharing with others, am not that expert but I found it just if I make the Panel Background image any image and place the GroupBox within the panel then in the backcolor of the GroupBOx choose Web > Transparent.
nothing else that should do all the work,

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a WPF solution, try the following.  Make sure to set Window.AllowsTransparency to true

```
<Window 
    AllowsTransparency="True" />

    <GroupBox Background="Transparent" />
</Window>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this in Visual Basic 6 you can do it using the following code:-

```
Option Explicit
Const THEBorder As Integer = 24 'You might need to adjust:
                                'this value is to compensate
                                'border of picturebox...
                                'note that I put a width of 2
                                'for this border, to make it
                                'wider
Private Sub Form_Load()
   With PicContainer
      .AutoRedraw = True
      .PaintPicture Me.Picture, 0, 0, , , .Left + THEBorder, .Top + THEBorder, .Width, .Height
   End With
End Sub
```

For further reference you can look [here](http://forums.codeguru.com/showthread.php?325547-Making-a-FRAME-transparent)